# Highcharts series data

Tags: highcharts

I am using fro drawing my spline chart. here is my series data example array:

```
data: [
    [1371563990000,1,530,100],[1373204470000,2,529,0],[1373464877000,0.5,531,50]
]
```

.

I want to access the fourth index value for the selected series. I am using `this.series.data[this.myIndex].config['z']` to get the third index value but don't know how to get the fourth index value.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to use object, instead of array,

```
{
   x: 1371563990000,
   y: 1,
   customParam1: 530,
   customParam2: 100
}
```

Paramaters will be available in point.options.customParam1